# my `onevent` custom method does not work in my class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, events

I'm creating a class to manipulate a websocket...

```
class MySocket{

    construct(url){
        this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
    }

    onevent(name, fn){
        this.socket.addEventListener(name, fn);
    }

    send(data){
        this.socket.send(data);
    }

    close(){
        this.socket.close();
    }    
}
```

Where I want to make a call to socket events `onopen | onclose | onmessage | onerror` in the style of Jquery...

```
const socket = new MySocket('ws://myurl');
socket.onevent('open', function(e){
    this.send('Hello World');
});
socket.onevent('message', function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
    this.close();
});
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I'm assuming you want something like `this.socket.addEventListener(name, fn.bind(this.socket));`

Comment: @Olian04 Works perfect, much very thanks